# Determine SQL Azure Region without using Admin Console

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am working on a solution that uses SQL Azure. Part of the project deals with backups and using the DAC Web Services for backups.

The issue is that there is a different endpoint depending on which region the Azure SQL database is in. As I am working with multiple groups, and cannot ensure which region the database will be in, I am looking for a way to programmatically determine the region.

The region is also important, as I want to copy the backups to a different region just to be on the safe side.

I know that I can look in the Admin console, but I would like to use code to solve this problem.

Additional information:

- The application is running on Azure using Worker Roles for functionality.
- I do not have access to all of the account-id's to use the full REST API.
- I do have access to the master database on the Azure Sql Server.
- Working on this in C# (I failed to put the language)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get Servers` request (`GET` `https://management.database.windows.net:8443/<subscription-id>/servers`) of Azure REST API to enumerate SQL servers which gives the Location or Region more info at msdn  -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715269.aspx

Comment: This does indeed work. The only problem is that I may or may not know the subscription-id for account. This solution is running from a worker role.

Comment: @maximumgeek: One way to work that around is to have the subscription id as a service configuration parameter which you setup once you decided under which subscription your service is deployed.